# COCOAPODS: Packaging Closed Source SDKs thru cocoapods-packager

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I am trying to create a private framework with dependencies of other pods. I will be hosting the podspec privately and wanted to distribute only a framework file thru pods. Found the cocoapods-packager since this is the recommended of cocoapods.

when trying to execute:

```
pod package ***.podspec --no-mangle --force --verbose
```

I always encounter this error.

```
    <unknown>:0: error: iOS 12 does not support 32-bit programs
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7s com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

I tried on the project files and xcconfigs to hardcode

> arm64 arm64e

and still i got the error mentioning about armv7 armv7s.

Where can I set the ARCHS of the cocoapods-packager?